# How do you see where in the assembly code a segmentation fault occurs?

Tags: x86, segmentation-fault, gdb

I know there is a gdb command that will show you which line in the .s file caused the seg fault, but I can't remember what it is and haven't been able to find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I know there is a gdb command that will show you which line in the .s file caused the seg fault

There is not. There *is* a command to show you disassembly:

```
(gdb) X/4i $pc
(gdb) disas $pc
```